# Excel run autofill only if the row has more than one data

Tags: vba, excel

On my row W, there is a calculation to divide column L and column D.

I'm using the VBA code  :

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("B666666").End(xlUp).Row

Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W" & LR)
```

However, if there is only one row of data (not including the header), the code breaks and gives

> AutoFill method of Range class failed.

So im wondering if its possible to run the autofill codes only when there's more than one data on column W?

Comment: have you tried to do it manually for one row while recording as macro? maybe that will give you a hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `If` criteria to check that `LR > 2`.

```
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("B666666").End(xlUp).Row
If LR > 2 Then '< -- check that there are more than 2 rows
    Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W" & LR)
Else
    ' do nothing ?
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("B666666").End(xlUp).Row
If LR > 1 Then Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("W2:W" & LR)
```

Change >1 to your desired value.